# Loading Large data as chunk by chunk into a webpage using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a text data that sizes around 200 MB. I need all of them to load on a web page for printing purposes (our client is not ready to compromise on this). This large text data located as 2mb string chunks in my data source. I wrote a script which actually load all these chunks one by one (one ajax call for each 2mb string) into browser. This ajax call fails after 30 - 40 calls and browser throws crash message 'Aw Snap!' (in chrome browser).

Here is my program...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function ajaxcall(i){
     $.ajax({url: "runs.php?g=data&chunk="+i, success: function(result){
        $("#data_load").append(result);
    }});
    
}

for(var i=1; i < 100; i++){
   ajaxcall(i);
}

});
```

Can some one give me an idea on how do i load these 200 MB of text data to  web page in some way ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a desktop app, not a web app, perhaps.

Comment: If it is supposed to be pure text, then I would probably not use `append`, which will involve parsing the data as HTML. And I would probably also rather not use any `someproperty += result` method that appends the new content to an already existing element, but rather create a new wrapper element for each chunk of text and append that to the document. (And btw., with the asynchronous nature of AJAX, it is probably not currently _guaranteed_ that you would be appending the chunks in a specific order.)

Comment: For me, it makes no sense to load this data in chunks. How it should make any better than loading it in one go?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxcall( i ) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "runs.php?g=data&chunk=" + i,
            success: function(result) {
                // Check data exist or not
                if (result) {
                    // If data exist in result then append and continue the loop for next page
                    $("#data_load").append(result); 
                    ajaxcall( i + 1)
                }
                else {
                    // if data not exist the print then stop the loop
                    console.log('All data loaded successfully');
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Initialize the AJAX call manually
    ajaxcall( 1 )
});
```

Comment: I hope this will help you. 
I didn't show you chunk. But, help to do sync the request.
By this solution your AJAX failed issue will resolved.

Comment: Would you explain to me "How the code not become helpful to you?"

Comment: I'm curious as to why it was given a poor rating. I can consequently greatly improve.